# Questions about nilpotence in commutative rings and zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, nilpotence

An element $a$ in a commutative ring $R$ is called nilpotent if $a^r = 0$ for some $r\in\Bbb N$.

$1.$ List all nilpotent elements in the ring $R = \Bbb Z/12\Bbb Z$.

$2.$ Let $a\in R\setminus\{0\}$ be nilpotent. Show that $a$ is a zero divisor.

My attempt:

$1.$ Because the prime factorization of $12=2^2\cdot3$, the prime factorization of $a$ contains $2,3$, so the nilpotent elements are $[0]_{12}$ and $[6]_{12}$. Is this correct?

$2.$ I'm having trouble on this one. :(

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. #2 is easier than you think: what does it mean to be a zero divisor? Suppose $0 \neq a \in R$ is nilpotent with $r$ minimal such that $a^{r} = 0$. Clearly, $r > 1$ since $a \neq 0$. Then $a^{r-1} \cdot a = 0$; why is $a^{r-1} \neq 0$?

Comment: @AlexWertheim Is is because r-1 is not the minimal, r is?

Comment: Yep. So what can you conclude?

Comment: @alexwertheim Yes! :) a is a zero divisor.

Comment: I don't see why what you wrote in (1) justifies your claim. You should probably explain it more.ç

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I was thinking that an element is nilpotent modulo 12 if it contains the numbers in the prime factorization of 12:2*2*3. the congruence class 6 modulo 12 and 0 modulo 12 were the only congruence classes modulo 12 that contain this prime factorization. For r>1 [6^r]=[0]. I think that's right at least, but I'll elaborate more. :)